# How to customize picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to customize picker view in my project. Add different type of image in pickerview cell & also want to reduce `pickerview` height.

I show you image for more understanding.

[image]

How to implement this type of pickerview? I check custom demo but I did not find any information.

Answer (score 0):

Apply condition to delegate method of UIPickerView.

```
  - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your image number %@.png", (long)row]];
UIImageView *imageview= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(-70, 10, 60, 40);

UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, -5, 80, 60)];
channelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:row]];
channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *tmpView_row = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 60)];
[tmpView_row insertSubview:imageview atIndex:0];
[tmpView_row insertSubview:channelLabel atIndex:1];

return tmpView_row;
}
```